# Adding multiple child nodes to the Parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create and XML file with data I am collecting, however for a particular  I need multiple sub tags to be generated

So I wish to have something like this:-

```
<Feedbacks>
   <Feedback>
     <Name></Name>
     <Surname></Surname>
     <Images>
       <Image></Image>
       <Image></Image>
       <Image></Image>
     </Images>
   </Feedback>
</Feedbacks>
```

Sorry do not know how to paste the correct XML file here, but I think you get the idea. At the moment I have this code that is working:-

```
    private static void CreateFeedbackXMLFile()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(docNode);

        XmlNode Node = doc.CreateElement("Feedbacks");
        doc.AppendChild(Node);

        string fileName = "Feedback.xml";
        string filePath = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultFolder + "\\" + fileName;

        doc.Save(filePath);
    }

    public static void InsertFeedback(Feedback feedback)
    {
        CreateFeedbackXMLFile();

        string filePath = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultFolder + "\\Feedback.xml" ;
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        XElement XParentElement = new XElement("Feedback");

        InsertIntoXMLDoc(feedback, filePath, xmlDoc);
    }


    private static void InsertIntoXMLDoc(Feedback feedback, string filePath, XDocument xmlDoc)
    {

        xmlDoc.Element("Feedbacks").Add(new XElement("Feedback",
                                        new XElement("Name", feedback.Name),
                                        new XElement("Surname", feedback.Surname),
                                        new XElement("Email", feedback.Email),
                                        new XElement("Website", feedback.Website),
                                        new XElement("Suggestion", feedback.Suggestion),
                                        new XElement("Error", feedback.Error),
                                        new XElement("MailingList", feedback.MailingList),
                                        new XElement("Comments", feedback.Comments)
                            ));

        }
        xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
    }
```

Now I need to loop through the imageList and create nodes according to how many images I have.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: you can use the code tags to paste the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is the way to go for what you are trying. In fact, there is no "loopless" way to achieve that. You can, however, disguise the loop as a `LINQ` query, with something like this:

```
xmlDoc.Element("Feedbacks").Add(
    /* All the elements before your image list */
    XElement("images", 
        from img in myImageList select new XElement(...)
    )
    /* All the elements after your image list, preceeded by a comma */
);
```

Of course, you'll need to replace `myImageList` with your actual collection of images. Note that if you have an `ImageList` control, the actual collection is not the control itself, but its `Images` property.

Also, on the `...`, you'll need to put whatever logics you are using to create each node from an image (using the auto-typed local variable `img` to refer to the appropriate image for each node).

Comment: Excellent reply, however I have encountered a problem now, which maybe you can help me in.  So my idea is to save the image to the XML, and then display it in a WPF form.  So when the Upload Image is happening in another form, I put it as a stream (System.IO.MemoryStream) and I can convert that and see it.  However I need to store this into an XML File, so that I can open it later, and obviously I cannot store it as a string.  I am also storing the result of the stream result = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());  Can I get this result to display the image from the XML file later?

Comment: Encoding to base64 is the sanest way to store the image on the XML. To display it again, you need to _create_ a new `Image` with the data recovered from the XML file. The issue here is that the `Image` class is abstract, so you need to use one of its subclasses. Most probably, `Bitmap` will do. Since none of its constructors take a byte array (what you'd get back from decoding the b64 data), you will need to create a MemoryStream with it to feed to the constructor. The full details are too long for a comment, so give it a try and create a new question if you have further issues ;)

Comment: Managed to get back the image and display it from the stream!

            byte[] mydata = Convert.FromBase64String(strResult);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(mydata);

Thanks a lot herenvardo for your excellent contribution

Comment: The ToArray is not necessary at all, the constructor of `XElement` takes a `params Object[] content` meaning you can pass in an arbitrary number of .NET objects. And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx explains that one possible type to add complex content is "Any type that implements IEnumerable<T>: If an object implements IEnumerable<T>, the collection in the object is enumerated, and all items in the collection are added". Thus ToArray is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Martin: thanks, fixed. I wonder what's doing the "magic" in there: a `params` argument is explicitly restricted to arrays, and I can find no overloads of the constructor actually taking the `IEnumerable`. Is there something that's not included on the documentation, or just the compiler doing some special-casing of these types?

Comment: The `params Object[] content` in C# (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) simply defines that you can pass in any number of additional arguments (of any .NET type as `Object` is the base type in .NET). The documentation I linked to earlier then defines which types are "understood" by LINQ to XML, `IEnumerable<T>` being one of them. When you do `new XElement("foo", from bar in baz select new XElement("whatever", bar.prop))` you pass one argument of type `IEnumerable<XElement>` for the params array, you could have more.

Comment: @Martin: thanks for the clarification. It seems I missed the `object` base type of the argument, and assumed it would be explicitly take `XObject`s or something like that. Maybe I'm just too fond of static type-safety =P